# Is it possible to use two parameter files for same export command Oracle 9i

Tags: oracle-9i

I want to export my database with the export **exp** command using a parameter file.
My constraint is that there is some tables I want to export without data, others with.
I'm having the idea of using two parameter files **PARAMFILE1**.dat and **PARAMFILE2.dat**.

- **PARAMFILE1**

  will contain **TABLES** parameter, mentioning tables to be exported without data, this by setting **ROWS** parameter to **n**.
- **PARAMFILE2**

  will contain **TABLES** parameter, mentioning tables to be exported with data, this by setting **ROWS** parameter to **y** (or not mentioning it at all, since it's Yes by default).

Is this possible ? If not, what is the best strategy for tackling this problem ?

Comment: What's wrong with running two exports? Since one doesn't have data, there's no consistency issue.

Comment: so the solution is simply to run the two export commands